# Medan - Samosir - Bukit Lawang - Medan roundtrip by tourist bus

Tags: public-transport, indonesia, sumatra-indonesia

I am looking for information about travelling in Sumatra Indonesia. I would like to go from Medan to Pulau Samosir then Bukit Lawang and back to Medan. I will have 9 people total so I have some bargaining power.  I've  emailed local agents who all seem to charge ridiculous amounts for private hire.

My question is do I need to prearrange the transport? Can I risk just showing up at the Pinang Bus station and speaking with minivan drivers? 
Is just showing up a bad idea for the Samosir to Bukit Lawang leg?

Alternatively, is the train from Medan to Sinjar worth a try?

Comment: You want to do all this in 2-3 days or would those legs be totally independant?